# update yaml file with yq version 4

Tags: json, yaml, yq

I've used the following command with `yq version 3` which work well

```
yq w -i  dep.yaml 'metadata.name' $(name)
```

the `name` is parameters which is coming from makefile

Now i've install version 4 and it stops working

I've try with something from here

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3

```
yq eval '.metadata.name = $(name)' dep.yaml
```

but it doesnt work, as im not sure how to pass right the parameter `$(name)` , any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `yq` v4, you can use the [`env()` function to lookup](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-string-environment-variable) values from the current enviornment. But this would mean the value of name has to be passed locally to yq invocation

```
name="FOO" yq eval '.metadata.name = env(name)' dep.yaml
```